# Find the sum of series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2+2k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, geometric-series, telescopic-series

Find the sum of the series.$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2+2k}$$

Which technique should I use? I tried but I cannot find anything.

Comment: Use partial fractions and get telescoping series. [Off hand get 2 such series to add]

Comment: Hint to use partial fractions: The denominator is k(k+2)

Comment: $\frac{1}{k(k+2)}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2})$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method using power series and double integrals. Let
$$ f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2+2k}x^{k+2} $$
and then
$$ f(0)=0,f'(0)=0, f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}x^{k+1}, \bigg(\frac{f'(x)}{x}\bigg)'=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}. $$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
f(1)&=&\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{x}{1-t}dtdx=\int_0^1\int_t^1\frac{x}{1-t}dxdt\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-t}\cdot\frac12(1-t^2)dt=\frac12\int_0^1(1+t)dt\\
&=&\frac34.
\end{eqnarray}